# django filter with user and profile model

Tags: django, profile, django-filter

I'm using the default User model that has a one-to-one relationship to the Profile model

I'm using django-filter to search for things, but it only works for the User model and nothing in the profile model works. How can I include the profile model into the search?

filters.py:

```
class AdminUserFilters(django_filters.FilterSet):
first_name = CharFilter(field_name='first_name', lookup_expr='icontains')
last_name = CharFilter(field_name='last_name', lookup_expr='icontains')
username = CharFilter(field_name='username', lookup_expr='icontains')
email = CharFilter(field_name='email', lookup_expr='icontains')

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email',)
```

models.py:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=8)
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

not tested.

```
class AdminUserFilters(django_filters.FilterSet):
   first_name = CharFilter(field_name='first_name', lookup_expr='icontains')
   last_name = CharFilter(field_name='last_name', lookup_expr='icontains')
   username = CharFilter(field_name='username', lookup_expr='icontains')
   email = CharFilter(field_name='email', lookup_expr='icontains')

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'userprofile__birthdate',)


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
         related_name='userprofile')
    birthdate = models.DateField(null=True, blank=False, max_length=8)
```

https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/usage.html#generating-filters-with-meta-fields

Comment: That works! I change named to profile instead of userprofile because it gave me errors for user.profile checks

Comment: @stelity if you set related_name='userprofile' it will work. anyway, your issue is resolved.

Comment: yes, it did work. I meant that it gave me errors for other thing such as {% if  user.profile.is_admin %}